# Paint on panel during runtime

Tags: java, awt, panel

I have a panel on which I want to draw stuff.
Painting on it when it is beeing created is no problem.

```
canvas = new Panel() {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 10);
    }
};
```

But then I want to draw on it during runtime.
By instinct, I've created something like this:

```
Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.drawLine(10, 10, 20, 20);
canvas.paint(g);
```

Sadly, this doesn't work.
This is probably a simple question but I cannot find a satisfying result by searching.
So how can I do what I want to do?

---

Sorry for the question above.
I just added the paint code on a button click event and it works.
It just doesn't work on the windowOpened event of the parent frame.
Any ideas why?

Comment: *"I have a panel on which I want to draw stuff"* Draw to a `BufferedImage` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the paint() method can be called at any time whenever the window system (or OS) decides that the particular graphical component needs to be repainted on screen. This may happen at any moment (most often when resizing, moving, switching windows, etc). To see how often it happens just add a log message at the beginning of paint() method. If you paint something on canvas just once it's very likely that it's painted, but then another repaint request comes from OS/window system and your green line gets "overdrawn" by object's paint() .
So the answer is that any custom painting should be done in paint(). You can add extra attributes to your subclass (eg. boolean drawGreenLine), check it in paint() and take any appropriate action, eg:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    boolean drawGreenLine;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 10);
        if (drawGreenLine) {
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.drawLine(10, 10, 20, 20);

        }  
    }
};
```

EDIT: As suggested by @MadProgrammer the example has been changed to override paintComponent(). This way the component is only responsible for drawing itself (and not any children or borders).

Comment: Change your example to use paintComponet and call it's super method and I'll be happy to up vote ... Mean aren't I :P

Comment: JPanel, paintComponent are used in Swing, not in AWT

Comment: @Hachi then use Panel and paint(), but the concept stays the same

Answer (score 0):

try `g.dispose()` to release the GraphicsContext's ressources

Comment: Only if you've created the graphics, with something lie g.create()

Comment: in awt the gc handling is a bit different than in swing. I often had similar problems and could solve them by disposing the gc

Comment: That doesn't make sense (to me), the only difference between AWT and Swing is that the AWT component has its own native peer where as Swing components share one (typically from the top level container) & support double buffering. [Check out the opening paragraph on Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing)