# Buttons in a buffered JFrame

Tags: java, swing, buffer, jbutton

Im pretty new to all the JFrame stuff and I have a problem. I need a JFrame with a buffer so it doesn't flicker all the times and I found a way to do that, but now I can't insert any JButtons anymore.

```
public class Window extends JFrame
{
    public Window()
    {
        setSize(800, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setLabel("Hello World");
        add(button);

        createBufferStrategy(2);
        buffer = getBufferStrategy();
    }

    public void repaint() 
    {
        Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();

        g.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

        //g.draw something

        g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
        g.dispose();
        buffer.show();
    }
}
```

All the answers I found so far, are just confusing me more than anything.

Comment: Just why do you need manual double buffering? Swing is double buffered by default.

Comment: Oh ... Well in that case, I have no Idea how to use that. I just wanted to draw a lot of BufferedImages in a loop without flickering and this was the method I came up with. How am I supposed to do it otherwise? Sorry for the stupid questions >.<.

Comment: Depends what exactly you need. Basically you can extend `JPanel`, and do the drawing in `paintComponent()` - swing will take care of the double buffering. More about custom drawing can be found in the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). If you need to draw the images in *sequence*, use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the delays (the obvious thing of drawing in a loop and sleeping in between *does not* work).

Comment: Thank you. The Tutorial seems to be quiet helpful.

Comment: There are at least 10 questions that pop up in a search on how to paint to components. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562614/paint-on-panel-during-runtime) is a simple one, but be sure to search before asking :)